# Can Outlook send a mail throgh two different SMPT at the same time?

Tags: vba, outlook

I have two accounts (two different SMTP servers) configured in Outlook, one is for external usage and the other is for internal usage. Due to DNS, they cannot be resolved by each other.

For instance, smtp.mail.a.com (internet) and smtp.mail.b.com (intranet)

I would like to send mails to external email address, but bcc a specific internal email address like abc@mail.b.com always.

Currently, I have to send to external email address firstly and then send the same email to the internal email address one more time.

Is there any script or work around can solve this issue which is able to send an email to both external and internal at once? Like the specified internal email account could be recognized automatically and send through by the specified SMTP?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

No, Outlook does not do that out of the box. But you can write a script or create a COM addin that tracks the Application.ItemSend event, detects that one server is being used, creates a copy of the email (mailItem.Copy), sets the account (#2) appropriately, then sends it (MailItem.Send).

Answer (score 0):

The [ItemSend](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865076(v=office.15).aspx) event of the Application class is fired whenever an Microsoft Outlook item is sent, either by the user through an Inspector (before the inspector is closed, but after the user clicks the Send button) or when the Send method for an Outlook item, such as MailItem, is used in a program.

So, in the event handler you can check out the [SendUsingAccount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869311(v=office.15).aspx) property which returns an Account object that represents the account under which the MailItem is to be sent. Be aware, the SendUsingAccount property can be used to specify the account that should be used to send the MailItem when the Send method is called. For example:

```
Sub SendUsingAccount()  
  Dim oAccount As Outlook.account  
  For Each oAccount In Application.Session.Accounts  
    If oAccount.AccountType = olPop3 Then  
      Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem  
      Set oMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)  
      oMail.Subject = "Sent using POP3 Account"  
      oMail.Recipients.Add ("someone@example.com")  
      oMail.Recipients.ResolveAll  
      oMail.SendUsingAccount = oAccount  
      oMail.Send  
    End If  
  Next  
End Sub
```

Most probably you will need to cancel the further processing of the  submitted mail item and re-send it programmatically after specifying the correct account.

Or just create a copy of the email, set the [SendUsingAccount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869311(v=office.15).aspx) account and send it programmatically (see the sample code).